# How can I break down multiple words seperated by comma and check against them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I have a list of 'tags' inside a field.  I'm trying to allow users to drill down search results using those tags.  Here's what the field looks like:

[image: field]

Say a user wants to search for 10 fr, male, intermittent catheter.  I can't use %like% because some of the tags are similar (ex: male, female).  Is there a way to break it into an array and search as you would in php?  Or something similar?

Ideally, I would like to seperate each keyword and compare each tag against the list to make sure they are ALL in there.

The closest I've been able to come up with is something like:

```
Select d.field_id_115 as tags,tag.tag_name, title.title, title.entry_id, cat_title.cat_name FROM finn_tagger tag LEFT JOIN finn_tagger_links link
                ON tag.tag_id = link.tag_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_channel_titles title
                ON link.entry_id = title.entry_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_category_posts cat
                ON title.entry_id = cat.entry_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_categories cat_title
                ON cat.cat_id = cat_title.cat_id
                Left JOIN finn_channel_data d
                ON cat.entry_id = d.entry_id
                WHERE cat_title.cat_url_title = 'catheter-supplies'
                AND tag.tag_name ='male'
                AND d.field_id_115 LIKE '%silicone%';
```

Alternatively, Each tag can also have it's own field, but I'm not sure how to make it check to ensure that if there are one or more tags, both tags are included.

[image: pic2]

So I would need to make sure that the entry_id has a record with each tag choice.  I tried to do that with the following:

```
SELECT  entry_id
                FROM (Select title.title, title.entry_id, cat_title.cat_name FROM finn_tagger tag LEFT JOIN finn_tagger_links link
                ON tag.tag_id = link.tag_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_channel_titles title
                ON link.entry_id = title.entry_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_category_posts cat
                ON title.entry_id = cat.entry_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_categories cat_title
                ON cat.cat_id = cat_title.cat_id
                Left JOIN finn_channel_data d
                ON cat.entry_id = d.entry_id
                WHERE tag.tag_name IN ('silicone')
                AND cat_title.cat_url_title = 'catheter-supplies'
                UNION ALL
                Select  title.title, title.entry_id, cat_title.cat_name FROM finn_tagger tag LEFT JOIN finn_tagger_links link
                ON tag.tag_id = link.tag_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_channel_titles title
                ON link.entry_id = title.entry_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_category_posts cat
                ON title.entry_id = cat.entry_id
                LEFT JOIN finn_categories cat_title
                ON cat.cat_id = cat_title.cat_id
                Left JOIN finn_channel_data d
                ON cat.entry_id = d.entry_id
                WHERE tag.tag_name IN ('male')
                AND cat_title.cat_url_title = 'catheter-supplies') as e
                group by entry_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But that just doesn't seem like the best way and it's pretty slow.

Comment: [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string on the comma then loop through the array and generate the query.

Comment: It looks like you have a bad DB schema. Can you edit/improve it? Or you have to deal with it?

Comment: I have to deal with it.  It's expressionengine with the tagger plugin.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll select the comma-separated database field you want to match against as follows:

```
SELECT REPLACE(comma_separated_field, ',', ' ') FROM some_table
```

Next, to break down the words, you'll need to use `explode()` as follows:

```
$search_term = '10 fr, male, intermittent catheter';
$search_term = explode(',', $search_term);
```

Finally, you'll want to match similar words with a like statement, note the spaces between the `%` symbols. This approach will successfully search for multiple exact matches like you want:

```
$like = '';
for($q=0; $q < count($search_term); $q++){
    if($q+1 != count($search_term)){
          $like .= "db_field LIKE '% " . $search_term[$q] . " %' AND ";
    }else{
          $like .= "db_field LIKE '% " . $search_term[$q] . " %'";         
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to do this in sql, not php.

Comment: Yes, I know, this approach prepares the query for sql and generates the exact results you want, by matching multiple words to one comma separated database field, based the input of the user.

Comment: I don't have a problem preparing the search terms.  I have a problem with the like.  If someone is searching male, 10fr, and foley.  It pulls all results that have the string "male", which include female, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Right, that is because you have your `like` statement set up as  `%male%` which matches  female. However, in the above example we're adding spaces, so now `% male %` wont match female.